# Plotting prime and double prime functions shows blank graph

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Im New to Mathmatica and I'm having an issue with plotting the functions found with NDSolve. My code:

```
M = 0.0289644;(*Molar mass of air*)
R = 8.31447;(*ideal gas const*)
Po = 101325;(*Preassure at Sea level*)
L = 0.0065;(*Temp lapse rate*)
To = 288.15; (*Sea level Temp*)
g = 9.8 ;(*Gravity*)
dC = 1.3;(*DragCoeff.*)
A = 0.4;(*Area of Cross Section*)
m = 117.934; (*Mass*)

Rho[h_] = ((Po*(1 - L*h/To)^(g*M/(R*L)))*M)/(R*(To - L*h));

Fd = NDSolve[{.5*dC*A*Rho[y[t]]*(y'[t]^2) - m*g == m*y''[t], y[0] == 40000, 
y'[0] == 0},{y[t]}, {t, 0, 300}]

Plot[y[t] /. Fd, {t, 0, 300}]

Plot[y'[t] /. Fd, {t, 0, 300}]

Plot[y''[t] /. Fd, {t, 0, 300}]
```

when plotting the position function, y[t], everything works fine, but plotting the velocity and accel functions are showing blank graphs. the x and y axis are still there, but the y range is only from -1 to 1. Not getting any messages, so not sure what is the issue here.

Answer (score 3):

This works. Used `y` instead of `y[t]` form.

```
fd=NDSolve[{.5*dC*A*Rho[y[t]]*(y'[t]^2)-m*g==m*y''[t],y[0]==40000,y'[0]==0},
      {y},{t,0,300}];

Plot[Evaluate[y[t]/.fd],{t,0,300}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[y'[t]/.fd],{t,0,300}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[y''[t]/.fd],{t,0,300},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to keep the original form, then this works:

```
fd=NDSolve[{.5*dC*A*Rho[y[t]]*(y'[t]^2)-m*g==m*y''[t],y[0]==40000,
     y'[0]==0},{y[t],y'[t],y''[t]},{t,0,300}]
```

And now you can do

```
Plot[y[t]/.fd,{t,0,300}]
Plot[y'[t]/.fd,{t,0,300}]
Plot[y''[t]/.fd,{t,0,300}]
```

And it will work.

And finally, if you want to keep your original expression as is, then this works

```
fd=NDSolve[{.5*dC*A*Rho[y[t]]*(y'[t]^2)-m*g==m*y''[t],y[0]==40000,y'[0]==0},
  {y[t]},{t,0,300}];

Plot[Evaluate@D[y[t]/.fd,t],{t,0,300}]
Plot[Evaluate@D[y[t]/.fd,{t,2}],{t,0,300}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. fixed my issue